# Angular template works but templateUrl does not

Tags: angular

Digging into Angular and the my-app component does not like the templateUrl. When I use the template all works fine. 
Expected output and what I get when using template:

hi there
LookUp Managment App

What I get when using templateUrl:
hi there

app.ts this works:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>hi there</h1><app-title> </app-title>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

title.ts works with the templateUrl:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-title',
    templateUrl:'Templates/Views/Lookups/title.html'
})
export class AppTitle {
    title="LookUp Managment App";
}
```

hit.html is:

```
<h1>hi there</h1>
<app-title></app-title>
```

title.html is:

```
<h4>{{title}}</h4>
```

When I swap my-app to this it no longer does the title

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: `Templates/Views/Lookups/hi.html`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

I am a bit confused why the templateUrl is working for the app-title component but not for the my-app component. Thanks for any assistance.

More Info:
I have added:

```
meta: {
                    './Scripts/*.js': {
                        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                    }
                }
```

As suggested it loads the hi.html file but it does not do anything with the  tag. It reacts to the  tag when it is in the template though.

Comment: I have a systemjs.config.js is that the same thing?

Comment: @RomanC I am not sure I understand your question. What can I show you to answer it?

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine all along. TypeScript compiles into what? What do browsers do with javascript? Cache can be such a pain in the rear.